# How long does Linux take to clear the heap memory

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, heap-memory, calloc

I was wondering... suppose I've dynamically allocated an array like

```
array = calloc(n, sizeof(float));
```

or something similar. And also if n is a really large number, (~ 1 million, for arguments sake), how long would Linux take to clear the heap memory if I didn't `free()` it at the end? I know any OS would go around and clear un-freed and unused heap memory areas. But I assume how long it takes to do that is OS dependent.

Comment: Not any longer than if you did free it, generally speaking.

Comment: Results in memory leak. re-claimed only during reboot.

Comment: @rjayavrp: no, absolutely not. Reclaimed at program exit. (Edge-cases might exist for embedded OSes without memory management.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a process is terminated (either voluntarily or by force), all its heap memory will be reclaimed *immediately* by an operating system including Windows, Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It would free the memory when your process has terminated. When a process termitates, all memory, open file handles and any resources opened by it, are closed by the system.

Comment: So can I assume that this process is almost instantaneous?

Comment: What do you mean? Why would it be instantaneous?

Comment: I mean does the OS keep track of the used heap memory and then deallocate it _as soon_ as the program terminates? Or does it take some time?

Comment: Ok, I understood. Yes, everything is reclaimed immediately when a process exits.

Comment: OS does not know about your heap. Heap is managed by C run time. OS only knows about memory pages. So either calloc and free methods hit to C run time heap. Do not confuse memory pages and heap.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely such a large amount of memory request will be satisfied by malloc/calloc. They are likely to return NULL.

`I know any OS would go around and clear un-freed and unused heap memory areas.`

No, OS doesn't look for unused heap areas. Assuming you have successfully allocated some memory dynamically (doesn't matter if it's small or large), OS doesn't de-allocate the memory for as long as the process is running, if you don't `free` it yourself.

When a process keeps requesting memory then it may be killed by the Out Of Memory killer on Linux.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify... I wanted to know _after_ the program has been terminated, if I haven't `free()`-ed my memory how long it would take for the OS to free it, if at all.

Comment: Once program exits, OS reclaims the memory on most platforms. I don't see any issue on Linux. But it's always good to free memory if you no longer need it.

Comment: “It's unlikely such a large amount of memory request will be satisfied by malloc/calloc. They are likely to return NULL.” It is 2012. When even mobile phones have 512MiB of memory, why would a program not be able to allocate 4MB? (~ 1 million floats)

Comment: @PascalCuoq That's why I used *unlikely* and answered with "Assuming you have successfully allocated..". Otherwise, someone else would have pointed me to embedded systems :)